# Is it possible to add objects and functions manually to Jedi-Vim?

Tags: python, python.net, jedi-vim

I created with pythonnet a interface for python to my C# project. To work in python I need auto completion for the C# import. I would write out the required objects and functions manually. But how to import these to Jedi-Vim?

Comment: In general you have to write stubs to make this kind of thing working. But I'm not sure I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Hi, so the problem cause pythonnet and the clr.AddReference() it is impossible for Jedi to load any object or function names. So my idea is to create a dummy file for that.

Comment: These dummy files are usually called stubs and have a file ending of `.pyi`. You should probably look that up.